# PHP convert string from windows-1250 to utf-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, web-crawler

I'm crawling windows-1250 site (meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250").

Since my database is utf-8, I need to convert data to utf-8.

For that job I tried iconv('windows-1250', 'UTF-8', $s); it gives "Ã„Åšarls" instead "Čarls".

It gives a bit better results when encodings switch places iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1250', $s);  gives "Èarls" instead "Čarls". Strange.

Do you have any idea how can I convert this to utf-8?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you 1000% sure the site you crawl is windows-1250? Can you make sure in the browser (see which encoding it switches to)? What is your output encoding?

Comment: How do you specify the character encoding of your output?

Comment: When you say "gives", what exactly do you mean? Can you cut the database out of the equation and try printing the converted result from your PHP code, with your own page encoding being UTF-8? Or have you done this already?

Comment: When I say gives, I mean what is written in the database (that's most important for me). Printed on utf-8  page it gives "ÄŚarls" iconv('windows-1250', 'UTF-8', $s) or "�arls" (iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1250', $s)). I expect "Čarls" which is from the original crawled site.

Comment: @umpirsky - general check list:

 1. mysql table schema to use utf-8  
 2. mysql clients connection to use utf-8 `mysql --default-character-set=utf8`  
 3. php `mysqli_set_charset` to utf-8  
 4. html encoding to utf-8  
 5. putty, emac clients... to be in utf-8

Comment: @ajreal Everithing is already in utf-8 except the site I'm trying to crawl :(

Comment: @umpirsky - some area must overlooked, such as how you view the results from mysql ? what is the `show variables like '%char%'` return?

Comment: Few characters can not be directly encoded to utf-8 from window-1250. Try to convert those few characters you mentioned to HTML entities. and then to utf-8.

Comment: @ajreal everithing is utf8 except character_set_server = latin1

Comment: @Satya Tried iconv('windows-1250', 'UTF-8', htmlentities($s)), same thing. Did you mean like that?

Comment: @umpirsky - back to this question, how you view the results return by mysql? which mysql client being used? how you connect to mysql client?

Comment: @ajreal I use SQLYog. It is set to use utf-8 since database and all tables are utf-8. Other utf-8 strings are visible ok, only from this site they are problematic.

Comment: @umpirsky = try `mb_detect_order(array('windows-1250', 'utf-8')); echo mb_detect_encoding(file_get_contents('YOUR_FILE'));`, It should echo `ASCII`

Comment: mb_list_encodings() gives Windows-1252, Windows-1254, Windows-1251, but no Windows-1250. I thought that have nothing to do with iconv :P I work on local windows machine, is there a way to add window-1250 if that is a problem?

Comment: @umpirsky - How is the crawling being done ? And results return by `print_r( mb_list_encodings() );` ?

Comment: @ajreal $client = new Zend_Http_Client(); $client->setUri($uri); $client->request()->getBody(); Result returned by mb_list_encodings should not afect iconv().

Comment: @umpirsky - Not too sure Zend_Http_Client change the behavior? From my end, i do not have windows-1250 support, but when i simply do file_get_contents and do the iconv, it works. And the mb_detect_encoding return ascii (which is true). So, maybe you want to start a test with a simple file_get_contents and test again the iconv?

Comment: It works on another windows server without encoding conversion! So, it must be sth with the server setup... mbstring setup is the same, must be some other thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folks, I'm really sorry. It was the database problem. $connection->setCharset('UTF8'); fixed it. No iconv, no mbstring.

I was so sure that I need to convert charset, that I forgot to check if it works on uft8 page without conversion.

Thanks for all comments.

Comment: at least you get it fixed (at last)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend first verifying whether or not the correct data is reaching iconv (and similarly what is going out from iconv).

Use a statement like `echo bin2hex($string)` and look at the byte stream for `$s` before iconv.  If you've got the string you believe you have the first byte should be `c8`.  If you then look at the byte stream after iconv the first bytes should be `c48c` (in UTF-8); if you convert to UCS-2 you'd see `010c` which you'll [see](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf) is the relevant character in unicode.

Depending on the results of this you'll know if your problem lies with gathering the data (i.e. you did not see the c8), your iconv installation (i.e. the conversion produces the wrong result) or putting that data into your database (i.e. the result of iconv is as expected).